# NX Monorepo not updating libraries with `nx-migrate`

Tags: angular, monorepo, nomachine-nx, nx-monorepo

I have created sample nx-monorepo for angular using v12. The original application is a polyrepo with angular cli using old version of lerna, so I am trying to upgrade it to 16 and want to go forward with `nx`.

Here is the structure.

```
Root
|-- apps
|   |-- app1
|   |-- app2
|-- libs
|   |-- lib1
|      | --package.json
|   |-- lib2
|      | --package.json
|--other-angular-and-nx-config-files
|--nx.json
|--package.json
```

Now when I run the nx migrate 13 command, it updated the root `package.json` file to version 13 but the `package.json` of angular libraries in the libs folder version still stays at 12. I have tried many resourses but did not find any useful documentation, not even in the `nx` documentation.

Comment: You can just remove package.json files from libs. That information will not be used anyway.

Comment: Even when we build and publish the library?

Comment: You do not build "libs", you only build "apps". They all will have deps that are declared in the root package.json.

Comment: I am using this libs outside of this nx project in other interfaces.

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to create a new repo with "publishable" libs (https://nx.dev/concepts/more-concepts/buildable-and-publishable-libraries), and copy source code there.